# Error between average of averages and true average

Tags: mean, error, differences

It is known that the average of averages can yield an incorrect result as compared to the true average.

The classroom example comes to mind: if the test results of class A is [50, 60, 100], class B is [20, 30] and class C is [40], what is the average test result of the whole school?

The true average should yield
$$\mu_{\mathrm{true}} = \frac{50 + 60 + 100 + 20 + 30 + 40}{6} = 50;$$

whereas taking each class average and then average over the number of classes yield
$$\mu_{\text{average of averages}} = \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{50 + 60 + 100}{3} + \frac{20 + 30}{2} + \frac{40}{1}\right) = \frac{70 + 25 + 40}{3} = 45.$$

What I'm interested in is the absolute difference $D = | \mu_{\mathrm{true}} - \mu_{\text{average of averages}} |$, where in the classroom example above,
$$D = |50 - 45| = 5.$$

That is, in the classroom example, the average of averages underestimates the true average by 5 points.

Is there any literature that tries to understand this error? Maybe there is a known bound on the error assuming a certain distribution on the samples? Can't seem to find any on the internet, maybe I'm searching the wrong keywords?

edit:

The reason why I'm interested in this quantity is because there are cases where I only get class averages (as in the example) rather than each individual values. I want to know how far off I am from the true average if I use average of averages in generality.

Comment: This is amenable to standard forms of analysis, such as ANOVA.  You might begin by studying *weighted* averages.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean ... see the Basic Example

Comment: I know that you can perform weighted average to correct the average of averages. What I care about is the case where I don't have the luxury of having the weights; and I'm trying to estimate the true average from these averages. Essentially, I want to know how far off I am from the true average if I use average of averages – is there a limiting case when the number of sample is large, etc.

Comment: Just a note that this is only one of the ways an "average of averages" can go wrong. Another is when you are averaging rates. If you drive from NYC to Boston at an average of 40 MPH and return at an average of 80 MPH (it's 4AM and no traffic). Then your average speed overall is not 60 MPH.

Comment: @PeterFlom Your example reminds me of [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) and the [mean of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) which might be a path toward deriving some sufficient conditions.

Comment: The question is obscure.  Are you perhaps asking what happens when these are *independent random samples?*  That would be fair, but then the answer depends on how you view the classes: are those presumed to vary randomly around the school average, or is there a hypothetical "true" average in each class that might vary between classes? This leads me to wonder what you're really trying to ask. One thing is guaranteed: the textbooks on ANOVA will cover all such possibilities thoroughly.